# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: group near line 1

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am getting an error while executing the query. The error is:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: GROUP near line 1, column 239 [SELECT j.orderDate, MAX(j.endTime), MIN(j.startTime) FROM fr.thelem.timesbatch.dao.entities.JobExecEntity j WHERE j.name=?0 AND TO_DATE(j.orderDate,'YYYYMMDD')>?1 AND TO_DATE(j.orderDate,'YYYYMMDD')

The query is:

```
Query query = this.em.createQuery(
      "SELECT j.orderDate, MAX(j.endTime), MIN(j.startTime) "
    + "FROM JobExecEntity j "
    + "WHERE j.name=?0 "
    + "AND TO_DATE(j.orderDate,'YYYYMMDD')>?1 "
    + "AND TO_DATE(j.orderDate,'YYYYMMDD')<?2 "
    + "AND NOT j.id=0 ORDER BY j.startTime "
    + "GROUP BY j.orderDate")
    .setParameter(0, nomChaine)
    .setParameter(1, new Date(Long.parseLong(start)*1000))
    .setParameter(2, new Date(Long.parseLong(end)*1000));
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY j.startTime` clause should be after the `GROUP BY j.orderDate` clause.